# SVN: How to copy a folder of a working copy and use as a working copy?

Tags: svn

In older version of svn (before 1.7), if I have a working copy and I would like to copy a part of it (say folder A) and use that as a working copy, I can just copy that folder A. No need to do a new checkout.

However since svn 1.7, that simple copy is no longer possible due to a new working copy format.

So, how do I copy a folder inside a working copy and use that as a new working copy in svn 1.7+ (without checkout) ?

Comment: I'd say that is not possible any longer, since the newer layout uses a global layout which you cannot separate. There is only one dumb workaround I can think of: copy the whole working copy and svn-reset everything _except_ for the folder you want to keep working on.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: To save some download time and bandwidth. I have a big checkout that I now want only a part of it. But that part is the largest.